# Can WPF/XBAP App be embedded in an HTML Page and call some javascript (like Flash does)

Tags: javascript, html, wpf

Can WPF/XBAP be embeded like Flash which can either run directly as swf or as embedded in an html page and communicate with it by calling javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can't do that with WPF/XBAP, you should take at Silverlight.

XBAP can run only in the browser but only "full page" with no html around it, non-XBAP WPF runs standalone only. Sliverlight can run as part of a page, I'm almost sure it can interact with javascript on the page and it can run "out of browser" (but not simply by double clicking on a file, you have to run it in a browser and have an "install" option in the app)

Comment: I think thats not 100% correct. You can embbed a XBAP application in a html page within an iframe.
The communication with JavaScript can be an issue. You can transmit a parameter in the link but otherwise i dont know..im also searching infos about interaction between javascript and Xbap

Comment: @catalin ilie - ok, but XBAP is still designed to run without any html or javascript around it and as such features that let it interact with the designed-to-be-non-existent javascript are probably not considered high priority (or, more likely, are not considered at all) so the point of my original answer is still true - if you need to interact with javascript XBAP is the wrong technology

Comment: @catalin ilie - and even if you could communicate with an XBAP the browser security would have stopped you, if not today then on the next service pack - let a web page communicate with some plugin in a different frame (that can potentially have full access to the local computer, not all plugins sandbox code running in them - and - isn't designed to run inside your page or you wouldn't need an iframe) sounds like a security problem waiting to happen to me.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still trying to find solution for this: I wrote a blog post containing information how this can be properly done. There is lots of outdated information, but this solution works with latest browsers.

[XBAP and Javascript with IE9 or newer](http://hotzblog.com/xbap-and-javascript-with-ie9-or-newer-solution-for-missingmethodexception-problems/)